# How to push array of string in formArray?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I need to create this:

```
instructions: ['value one' , 'value two' , 'value three'];
```

I am using formArray and check my code on stackblitz first:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/formarray-obj?file=app/app.component.ts

html:

```
<div class="form">
    <form id="form" [formGroup]="filmForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">
        <button type="button" (click)="addItem()"> add new row</button>
        <div formArrayName="instructions" *ngFor="let a of filmForm.get('instructions').controls; let i = index">
            <div [formGroupName]="i" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" formControlName="instructions">
                <br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="submit">
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

TS:

```
registerForm: FormGroup;
submitted = false;
instructions: FormArray;
filmForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.filmForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        instructions: this.formBuilder.array([this.createItem()])
    })
}

createItem() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
        instructions: ['']
    })
}

addItem() {
    this.instructions = this.filmForm.get('instructions') as FormArray;
    this.instructions.push(this.createItem());
}

save() {
    console.log(this.filmForm.value)
}
```

I am sending array of object: check stackblitz console.log
I am send like

```
instructors = [{instructs : 'value one'} , {instructs : 'value one'}..]
```

But I need to sent:

```
 instructors = ["value one" , "value two"];
```

Comment: I don't think so till Angular v8. #Following

Comment: I don't understand ? What about v8 ?

Comment: I mean Till Angular version 8.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46163954/11719787) might help you

Comment: You can use rxjs to format your data: `console.log({ instructions: this.filmForm.value.instructions.map(e=> e.instructions) });`. have a look on my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/formarray-obj-kkszod

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.. i had the same issue.

Make the Form

```
form = new FormGroup({
instructorsArray: new FormArray([]),
})

  get instructors(): FormGroup {
    return FormControl('')
  }

 addInstructors() {
    this.instructors.push(this.instructors);
  }
```

Comment: What is this.pegadio??

Comment: sorry,    this.instructors.push(this.instructors);

Comment: made a change to better understand.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which you go ahead with this.

### 1 - Using .map in save()

For the desired output, you can use the `.map` in `save()` function:

```
save() {
  const instructions = this.filmForm.value.instructions.map(inst => inst. instruction);

  console.log(instructions);
}
```

Desired Output will be:

```
["value one" , "value two"]
```

### 2 - Using a tags input control like ng-select

Your use case looks like a tags control use case for instructions.
There is a popular library [@ng-select/ng-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select) which has a [tags](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/tags) control.

You can see the usage of this library for your use case on [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-tags-example).

Approach 1 is the easiest one to do but I would suggest you use tags control in approach 2 for good user experience.

Comment: Ok I got this value...but how to append to my form...this values....

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to do with the values?
And also, which approach are you following?